# скрипт рассматривает только первый элемент списка

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, у меня имеется код для парсинга двух файлов в определённой директории, вот код:

```
dir = 'C:\python\input'
for txt in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir,'*.txt')):
    with open(txt, newline='') as input:
        ats = ['1','2']
        for a in ats:          
                reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = ' ')
                angles = []
                for row in reader:
                    if row[2] == a:
                        angles.append(row[4])
                print(a,angles)
```

однако, на выходе я получаю вот это:

```
1 ['114.32', '102.62', '114.12', '100.02', '118.02', '104.93']
2 []
1 ['94.02', '95.42', '174.32', '95.62', '164.11', '86.21', '90.01', '85.71', '101.81', '78.71']
2 []
```

Может ли кто-нибудь помочь с этим, почему второй элемент списка скрипт не рассматривает?
пример входного файла:

```
fNumber m1 m2 m3 Angle
a1 3 1 6 84.92
a2 3 1 12 93.12
a3 3 1 13 144.52
a4 3 1 14 162.22
a5 3 2 15 89.22
a6 3 2 16 81.32
a7 3 2 20 74.92
a8 6 3 12 79.52
a9 6 3 13 129.92
```

когда я поменял циклы местами, программа стала выдавать результат только насчёт двойки, а единицу не показывает вовсе

```
reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = ' ') 
angles = [] 
n = 0 
out = [] 
for row in reader: 
    ats = ['1','2'] 
    for a in ats: 
        if row[2] == a: 
            n += 1 
            angles.append(row[4]) 
print(a,angles)
```

Comment: Вы специально? Вы же видите, что в данных, которые Вы показали, нет двойки в третьем столбце.

Comment: нет, я просто показал не весь файл, он очень длинный, поэтому двойки где-то внизу

Comment: Никто не ждет от Вас такой честности. Покажите маленький, но репрезентативный файл. Вы же маленький файл используете для отладки :) ?

Comment: Каким образом из входного файла должен получиться выходной?

Comment: а почему должен получаться выходной ФАЙЛ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл это итератор в Питоне. Потребив значения один раз (когда `a=='1'`) вы не получите больше значений (пусто для `a=='2'`):

```
>>> it = iter(range(5))
>>> list(it)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(it)
[]
```

В вашем случае, вы можете перенести открытие файла внутрь ats цикла.

Есть алгоритмы, которые не требуют читать файл несколько раз. Можно за один проход сгруппировать значения пятого поля по интересующим значениям третьего и вывести в формате, используемом в вопросе с помощью `collections.defaultdict` (набросок):

```
from collections import defaultdict

g = defaultdict(list)
for row in csv.reader(file, **dialect):
    if row[2] in ats:   # if interesting 
        g[row[2]].append(row[4])  # add to the group

for a in ats:  # display groups
    print(a, g[a])
```

Если строки отсортированы по значению третьего поля (как пример в вопросе), можно `itertools.groupby()` использовать для группировки значений:

```
from itertools import groupby

for a, group in groupby(reader, key=lambda row: row[2]):
    if a in ats:  # interesting 
        print(a, [row[4] for row in group])  # display group
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

def parse_file(filename):
    return (pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True)
              .groupby('m2')['Angle']
              .agg(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
              .to_dict())
```

Проверка:

```
In [169]: parse_file(filename)
Out[169]:
{1: [84.92, 93.12, 144.52, 162.22],
 2: [89.22, 81.32, 74.92],
 3: [79.52, 129.92]}
```